# What is the difference between the build and create method in ActiveRecord relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User who can have 0 or 1 Profiles. In my Controller, I want to save the profile if some of the values are given, as follows:

```
# PUT /users/1
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    if params[:profile][:available] == 1 #available is a checkbox that stores a simple flag in the database.
      @user.create_profile(params[:profile])
    end
  else 
    #some warnings and errors
  end
end
```

The part I am wondering about is `create_profile`, the magic `create_somerelationname`. How does that compare to the magic `build_somerelationname`? And when should I use which?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference between `build` and `create` is that create also saves the created object as build only returns the newly created object (without it being saved yet).

The documentation is somewhat hidden away [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).

So, depending whether you are happy with the returned object or not, you need `create` (since you will not change it anymore) respectively `build` as you want to update it before saving again (which will save you a save operation)

Answer (score 13):

`@user.build_profile` is the same as

```
Profile.new(:user_id => @user.id)
```

while `@user.create_profile` is the same as

```
Profile.create(:user_id => @user.id)
```

`@user.create_profile` can be presented with `build_profile` like this:

```
profile = @user.build_profile
profile.save
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Answer (score 9):

From the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference)

> **build_association(attributes = {})**
>
> The build_association method returns a new object of the associated
>   type. This object will be instantiated from the passed attributes, and
>   the link through its foreign key will be set, but the associated
>   object will not yet be saved.
>
> **create_association(attributes = {})**
>
> The create_association method returns a new object of the associated
>   type. This object will be instantiated from the passed attributes, and
>   the link through its foreign key will be set. In addition, the
>   associated object will be saved (assuming that it passes any
>   validations).

What you should use depends on the requirement. Generally the `build_association` is used in the new method.